# Problem with creating a new constructor in Java

Tags: java, list, stack, polynomial-math

I am trying to create a new constructor for the Monomial, but I keep getting the error

```
"return type is missing for coefficient"
```

Why is that so because constructors in java has no return type so why is the compiler is asking for a return type?

Additionally, how can I initialise  private PolyNode monomilaist insider the constructor since it is private, and not public?

```
public class Polynomial implements CalculatorOperand<Polynomial> {


private class PolyNode {
    int coeff;
    int degree;
    PolyNode next;



    public Monomial(int coeff, int degree)
    {
        private PolyNode monomialsList; 
    }
```

Comment: That's not valid Java syntax; you cannot create fields inside a constructor (unless you want to create a local class, but you don't)

Comment: Please put the whole java code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, it looks like there is a significant skill/knowledge gap.  I recommend focusing on finding and going through a Java tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

**First** a constructor needs to have the same name as the class.

**Secondly** a variable in a method may not have any modification like `public`, `private` or `protected`. It is only visible in the method anyway.

```
private class Monomial {
    int coeff;
    int degree;
    PolyNode next;



    public Monomial(int coeff, int degree)
    {
        PolyNode monomialsList; 
    }
```

Comment: I revised my code. However, I am still getting the error that coeff and degree cannot be resolved to a variable. How can I fix this?

         `{ public class Polynomial implements CalculatorOperand<Polynomial> {


 private class PolyNode {
  int coeff;
  int degree;
  PolyNode next;
  
  

  
 }
 
 Polynomial Monomial= new Polynomial(coeff, degree, null);
 
 private PolyNode monomialsList; }`

Comment: Well, I answered your question you put, I can not know whatever else is in your code. Open a new Question for new problems.